# Recuperar valor do label de um select HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Possuo o seguinte select:

```
<span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Órgão: </span>
<select name="Distrito" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
    <option value="01">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
    <option value="02">Coordenadoria de Governo e Comunicação Social</option>
    <option value="03">Secertaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
    <option value="04">Procuradoria Jurídica</option>
    <option value="05">Ouvidoria Municipal</option>
    <option value="06">Secretaria Municipal de Administração</option>
</select>
```

Gostaria de recuperar não só o value, mas o label também, como poderia ser feito?

Comment: Por que utilizou a tag `PHP` na pergunta? Queres saber como isso se faz com PHP (embora não tenha jeito somente com PHP) ou Javascriot?

Comment: em qualquer uma dessas eu poderia utilizar, pois se trata de um sistema web que uso essas tecnologias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Javascript puro, tal como a tag da pergunta, altere o `select` para executar uma função quando o valor for alterado, através do evento `onchange`:

```
 <select name="Distrito" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1" onchange="mudouValor()">
```

Crie a função `mudouValor`, responsável por obter o valor da label:

```
 function mudouValor() {
      //instancia um elemento do DOM através do respectivo id, que nesse caso é "COMBOFAB"
      var elemento = document.getElementById('COMBOFAB');
      //com o elemento instanciado, é possível capturar o valor da label
      var texto = elemento.options[elemento.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
 }
```

Diretamente com PHP não será possível. Entretanto poderá utilizar Javascript para preencher um campo do tipo `hidden` no seu formulário, por exemplo:

```
 <form name="myform" id="myform" action="teste.php" method="POST">
     <span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Órgão: </span>
     <select name="Distrito" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1" onchange="mudouValor()">
         <option value="01">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
         <option value="02">Coordenadoria de Governo e Comunicação Social</option>
         <option value="03">Secertaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
         <option value="04">Procuradoria Jurídica</option>
         <option value="05">Ouvidoria Municipal</option>
         <option value="06">Secretaria Municipal de Administração</option>
     </select>
     <input type="hidden" name="label" id="label" />
</form>
```

Repare que foi adicionado no fim do formulário o campo do tipo `hidden` com o `value` preenchido com o valor da primeira opção do `select`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="label" id="label" value="Gabinete do Prefeito" />
```

O problema de inicializar manualmente o campo `label` com o valor correspondente ao primeiro elemento do `select` é que se esse valor mudar, o programador precisa de alterar também o `value` do campo `label` e com certeza alguém vai esquecer disso no futuro, então podemos automatizar essa parte:

```
window.onload = function(){
    mudouValor();
}
```

O código Javascript ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
function mudouValor() {
      var elemento = document.getElementById('COMBOFAB');
      var texto = elemento.options[elemento.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

      //altera o valor do campo cujo o id seja igual a "label"
      document.getElementById("label").value = texto;
 }

 window.onload = function(){
    mudouValor();
 }
```

Repare que para o exemplo, o formulário está com o atributo `action` definido com o valor `teste.php` e com o atributo `method` com o valor `POST`, ou seja, será feito um POST Request para o ficheiro `teste.php`:

```
  <form name="myform" id="myform" action="teste.php" method="POST">
```

Com isso basta criar o ficheiro `teste.php`:

```
  <?php
      //Através da variável global "$_POST" é possível obter os valores do seu formulário.
      //Cada index do array "$_POST" representa um campo do formulário, ou seja, no formulário existe um campo com o atributo name="Distrito" e outro campo com o atributo name="label"
      $distrito = $_POST['Distrito'];
      $label= $_POST['label'];

      //...
  ?>
```

Altere os nomes conforme a sua necessidade, os nomes acima foram definidos apenas para efeito de exemplo.

Comment: dessa forma eu recupero somente o selecionado ou todos?

Comment: Somente o selecionado, veja a variável `texto` dentro da função `mudouValor`, ela é preenchida de acordo com o elemento selecionado e isso é possível utilizando o `elemento.selectedIndex` juntamente com `elemento.options`.

Comment: esse select já estava dentro de um form, era esse: <form method="post" action=""> é necessário colocar name e id?

Comment: Não é necessário colocar um `name` ou `id` no formulário. Terá que criar o campo `hidden` que citei acima dentro do formulário e alterar o `select` adicionando o evento `onchange`, tal como explicado acima.

Comment: fiz essas modificações, mas não deu certo, tô vendo se tem algo errado aqui

Comment: Veja na console do browser se existe algum erro de javascript. O javascript funciona, [veja aqui um exemplo.](https://jsfiddle.net/twxuc3zp/)

Comment: teria algum problema em ter outros inputs no form?

Comment: @V.Avancini não, desde que não tenham o mesmo ID. Se alterar o ID do campo `hidden` que criamos, então é preciso alterar a função `mudouValor`  para considerar o novo ID.

Comment: por algum motivo o $_POST não tá enviando as informações

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70863/discussion-between-filipe-moraes-and-v-avancini).

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o [Jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)(que eu recomendo vocÊ adicionar ao seu projeto caso não tenha):

```js
console.log($("#COMBOFAB option:selected" ).text()); //texto do item selecionado
console.log($("#COMBOFAB option:selected" ).val()); //valor do item selecionado
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Órgão: </span>
<select name="Distrito" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
    <option value="01">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
    <option value="02">Coordenadoria de Governo e Comunicação Social</option>
    <option value="03">Secertaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
    <option value="04">Procuradoria Jurídica</option>
    <option value="05">Ouvidoria Municipal</option>
    <option value="06">Secretaria Municipal de Administração</option>
</select>
```

Utilizando Javascript puro:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("COMBOFAB");
var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

console.log(selectedValue); //valor do item selecionado

console.log(selectedText); //texto(label) do item selecionado
```

```html
    <span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Órgão: </span>
    <select name="Distrito" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
        <option value="01">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
        <option value="02">Coordenadoria de Governo e Comunicação Social</option>
        <option value="03">Secertaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
        <option value="04">Procuradoria Jurídica</option>
        <option value="05">Ouvidoria Municipal</option>
        <option value="06">Secretaria Municipal de Administração</option>
    </select>
```

EDIT: Recomendo você utilizar o Jquery, além de ser mais limpo, você terá mais um monte de facilidades na palma de sua mão, para adicionar o Jquery via CDN você pode colar esse código no Layout do seu projeto, ou nas paginas que você vai utilizar:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: como faria para armazenar em um variável em php?

Comment: $var = $("#COMBOFAB option:selected" ).text()); ??

Comment: @V.Avancini vou descobrir, faz tempo que não uso PHP

Comment: se vc conseguir e mandar aqui marco como aceito

Comment: Vou descobrir, mas caso alguem encontre, avontade para marcar como correto ;)